# Badges for cleaning up

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, badge-request, stack-exchange

Add more badges for cleanup tasks, like closing questions

Comment: any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Closed 10 or 20 questions with a unanimous vote
- Closed 10 or 20 questions as duplicate

This prevents (or tries to prevent) negative and pointless voting to get badges. Since you have to select a duplicate and you have to select a correct close type.

There is one problem though with the first one. It forces that people vote the same if they want to get the badge. So if the first person picks the wrong thing, the others have to pick the wrong thing with him to get a badge.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure I like the idea of rewarding the removal of content. I realize that in most cases the questions closed aren't useful / don't belong / whatever, but I strongly believe that people should be rewarded for **creation** as opposed to otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

This has been implemented by the addition of the /review queues and badges for completing 1, 250 and 1000 reviews of each type (including closing)